# Using a dictionary to update one attribute based on another

Tags: arcpy, cursor, dictionary

I need to update a large dataset based on information in an Excel table. I figured the easiest way to do this would be using a dictionary I can fill out from the Excel table and run it on a feature class in a FGDB. Here is my code:

```
import os, arcpy

sitepoly = r'CodeTest'
AreaID = "907"##Change to current site

uCur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(sitepoly)
hs = uCur.next()
missingCnt = 0

while hs:
    OID = str(hs.getValue("OBJECTID"))
    gsID = str(hs.getValue("SITEMARKER_ID"))
    ##Define Datatypes from Excel using a dictionary here:
    ##Replace these values for different sections
    size= {"EE1":"3x8",
           "S":"3x8",
           "EE3":"5x10",
           "EE4":"3x8"}
    if gsID.startswith(AreaID):
        sectionID = str(hs.getValue("SECTION"))
        sizeattribute = str(hs.getValue("SITE_SIZE"))
        try:
            if len(sizeattribute) < 3 and sectionID == size:
                hs.setValue("SITE_SIZE", size)
                print str(gsID) + " has had the site size updated."
            uCur.updateRow(hs)
        except:
            missingCnt = missingCnt + 1
    hs = uCur.next()
del uCur
```

The code will finish, but "SITE_SIZE" is not updating with anything in the dictionary. For clarification: Each AREA has multiple SECTIONS and each SECTION has multiple features which I'm trying to update. Any ideas?

Comment: what is your version of arcGIS ? if >= 10.1 you should use the "da" cursor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, [data access cursors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) have been the recommended cursor since ArcGIS 10.1. Using them streamlines the code and the processing itself. It tends to be cleaner and more concise.

That said, the reason you're not getting any data to update is that you seem to be confusing the dictionary itself with the values in the dictionary. Because of this, it's not quite clear what you're trying to do.

So, I'm working off the assumption that your dictionary named *size* maps section names to their intended sizes. Here's a solution that changes two lines...I've retained but commented out the erroneous lines and put the correct lines directly beneath them:

```
import os, arcpy

sitepoly = r'CodeTest'
AreaID = "907"##Change to current site

uCur = arcpy.UpdateCursor(sitepoly)
hs = uCur.next()
missingCnt = 0

while hs:
    OID = str(hs.getValue("OBJECTID"))
    gsID = str(hs.getValue("SITEMARKER_ID"))
    ##Define Datatypes from Excel using a dictionary here:
    ##Replace these values for different sections
    size= {"EE1":"3x8",
           "S":"3x8",
           "EE3":"5x10",
           "EE4":"3x8"}
    if gsID.startswith(AreaID):
        sectionID = str(hs.getValue("SECTION"))
        sizeattribute = str(hs.getValue("SITE_SIZE"))
        try:
            ##if len(sizeattribute) < 3 and sectionID == size:
            if len(sizeattribute) < 3 and sectionID in size:
                ##hs.setValue("SITE_SIZE", size)
                hs.setValue("SITE_SIZE", size[sectionID])
                print str(gsID) + " has had the site size updated."
            uCur.updateRow(hs)
        except:
            missingCnt = missingCnt + 1
    hs = uCur.next()
del uCur
```

And here's a version that uses a data access cursor, removes extraneous code (e.g., OBJECTID was never used), and applies some other Python/ArcPy best practices (e.g., uses context manager for cursor, uses string formatting):

```
import os, arcpy

sitepoly = r'CodeTest'
AreaID = "907"##Change to current site

missingCnt = 0

size= {"EE1":"3x8",
       "S":"3x8",
       "EE3":"5x10",
       "EE4":"3x8"}

cursor_fields = ['SITEMARKER_ID', 'SECTION', 'SITE_SIZE']
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(sitepoly, cursor_fields) as cur:
    for row in cur:
        gsID, sectionID, sizeAttribute = row
        if gsID.startswith(AreaID) and len(str(sizeAttribute)) < 3:
            try:
                row[-1] = size[sectionID]
                print('{} has had the site size updated.'.format(gsID))
                cur.updateRow(row)
            except KeyError:
                missingCnt = missingCnt + 1
        else:
            print('If statement not satisfied:\n\tgsID: {}\n\tsectionID: {}\n\tsizeAttribute: {}'.format(gsID, sectionID, sizeAttribute))

print('Missing: {}'.format(missingCnt))
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, Tom! I tried both versions of the script but am coming up with same result; script runs and finishes but nothing is updated. Your assumption is correct. Each Area has dozens of Sections, each Section has hundreds or thousands of plots(features). Each plot needs to have the size in the "SITE_SIZE" attribute filled out according to it's SectionID (in this case I'm testing the code on four sections: EE1, S, EE3, and EE4).

Comment: Thank you for the tips, I am reading up on UpdateCursor now

Comment: @MattD, Are your if conditions satisfied in the table? What are the existing values for size in the table? Are they less than three characters long? You can test it with the code I just updated...the second code block, with the da cursor. It will print a notification for each row that doesn't satisfy the if statement, along with the existing values in that row.

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much! It turns out my IF statement was predicated on there being SOME kind of value already present, but that field is Null. It's working. Thank you so much!!